# Doesn't navigate the url to Youtube channel in ios Ionic cordova

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to navigate youtube channel when we click on button in ios, but it was not working, it is perfectly working in android …

Below are the my reference

**HTML file**

```
<ion-button class=“youtube_btn” (click)=“openYoutube()”>Our youtube channel</ionic-button>
```

**TS file**

```
import { DomSanitizer } from ‘@angular/platform-browser’;

constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
this.getSafeUrl(“https://www.youtube.com/embed/FSFTBf7frUs”);
}
openYoutube(){
window.open(‘https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp7eM4-x4K4AeSkiRHfxDbQ’, ‘_system’, ‘location=yes’);
}

getSafeUrl(url) {
this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/898#issuecomment-643697420

Comment: ERROR in src/app/tab1/tab1.page.ts:28:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cordova'.
[ng] 28     cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.google.com', '_system', 'hidden=yes,location=no')
[ng]        ~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

**In App Browser**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

**App Availability**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-appavailability
npm install @ionic-native/app-availability
```

**After installing both the Ionic native plugin we should enlist the InAppBrowser and AppAvailability provider with the principle application module.**

**After that add below code in app.module.ts**

```
import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    AppAvailability,
    InAppBrowser
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**After that import those two modules in your component Typescript file**

```
import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private appAvailability: AppAvailability,
    private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }

  openYoutube() {
    let app;
    let channel = 'paste Url of your channel'
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      app = 'youtube://';
    } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      app = 'com.google.android.youtube';
    } else {
      const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.inAppBrowser.create('https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + channel, '_system');
      return;
    }

    this.appAvailability.check(app)
      .then(
        (yes: boolean) => {
          console.log(app + ' is available')
          // Success
          // App exists
          const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.inAppBrowser.create('youtube://channel?id=' + channel, '_system');
        },
        (no: boolean) => {
          // Error
          // App does not exist
          // Open Web URL
          const browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.inAppBrowser.create('https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + channel, '_system');
        }
      );
  }
}
```